# Understanding why my code reverses a number

Tags: java

So I came across this code on the web and I am trying to wrap my head around how the code is reversing the number order. Can someone help me out? Additionally, is there a way I can change the while loop into a for loop? I don't see an increment so the code is throwing me off just a little.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class Challenge{ 

 public static void main(String args[]){ 

///{write you code here  
 int n, reverse = 0;

      System.out.println("Enter the number to reverse");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      n = in.nextInt();


      while( n != 0 )
      {
          reverse = reverse * 10;
          reverse = reverse + n%10;
          n = n/10;
      }
 ///}  

  System.out.println("Reverse is :"+reverse);  
} 

}
```

Comment: Start debugger and follow the sequence, I think you'll understand the rest!!

Comment: Or, if you prefere, you could walk through the code on paper ;)

Comment: @DylanMeeus good old times indeed!

Comment: Better to spend some time on For loop,while loop,and do while loop then you can understand easily by yourself....)

Comment: My strategy is to program on loops this week. Which I have been. I only come on here when I feel I spent too much time trying to figure something out.

Comment: How much time is "*too much*" for you?

Comment: I understand the reason for concern. However, I am offering an opportunity for someone with some experience to learn from the code and offer an explanation. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @user3113390: every time you do this (`n = n/10;`) you're actually decrementing it.

Comment: `My strategy is to program on loops this week.`  Your 'strategy' or your assignment from a programming class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your number is `123`.  The first time through the loop, `reverse` starts off at `0`, so this line, does nothing.

```
reverse = reverse * 10;
```

This line, however, takes the last digit of n.

```
reverse = reverse + n%10;
```

So now, `reverse` is `3`.
The last line, divides `n` by 10, discarding any remainder

```
n = n/10;
```

So now `n` is `12`.

The second pass through the loop, the following happens:

```
reverse = reverse * 10;
```

`reverse` is now `30`.

```
reverse = reverse + n%10;
```

`reverse` is now `32`.

```
n = n/10;
```

`n` is now `1`.

Last time through the loop:

```
reverse = reverse * 10;
```

`reverse` is now `320`.

```
reverse = reverse + n%10;
```

`reverse` is now `321`.

```
n = n/10;
```

`n` is now `0`.